# How to convert a textbox's text into a value?

Tags: c#

I have this expression in my code

```
label3.Text = (((2 * 4.1) * 2) + (2 * textBox1.Text) + 31.6).ToString();
```

But I need the textBox1.Text value to evaluate the expression and the answer to be stored in the text of label3. So I should be able to change the textBox1 text to anything like 2, 3, etc and it should evaluate the expression and place the answer into label3.Text.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the project?

Comment: This programm is for edit game skill.For example i have skill whose damage =  (((level* 4.1) * level) + (level * 93.8) + 31.6).I need to change only one value,It's 93.8.Other values are invisible for user.But users will know how much damage will have skill,if he write 445,4(for example)in textbox.Programm works with binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking.

You will need to first check that the value in the text box is a number, then use it to perform the calculation.

```
label3.Text = (((2 * 4.1) * 2) + (2 * Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)) + 31.6).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.But there is one problem.Programm is not hard,but it is big.It contains greater than 200 textboxes.Everyone has own formula(own label).So cant i do that in one line?

Comment: Sure. I just edited my answer to do exactly that. Be careful with this method, though - you should really be testing the value in the text box first to see if it is actually a number.

Comment: It doesn't work.There is a mistake with mscorlib.dll.

Comment: I understand that it's because of empty textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so first you should get the value from the first textbox and convert it into a double or decimal or whatever you are using. Do that with this

```
double textbox1_Value = Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text);
```

Now you can insert the textbox1_Value into that location and since it is a double it can now evaluate an answer.

So your code would be

```
label3.Text = (((2 * 4.1) * 2) + (2 * textbox1_Value) + 31.6).ToString();
```

Personally, if you are not using data binding I would throw that into a try catch block because what if the textbox value is not a double? How I would go about it:

```
try
{
    double textbox1_Value = Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error, unable to parse text");
    return;
}
label3.Text = (((2 * 4.1) * 2) + (2 * textbox1_Value) + 31.6).ToString();
```

So if something goes wrong when trying to convert it to a double, it will catch it, you can display an error and close the program or return out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved.Thanks.

private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

try

{

label1.Text= (((2*4.1)*2)+(2* Convert.ToDouble(textbox1.Text)+31.6).ToString();

}

catch

{

}